# R shiny code to get output which takes input from ui

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write a script in shiny, which has two inputs and stores the inputs in two different variables and runs a code using these input variables.But i am getting an error which says :Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
The following is my ui code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Network Model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "origin",
                  label = "Origin:",
                  choices = milk_runs$Origin),
      selectInput(inputId = "destination",
                  label = "Destination:",
                  choices = milk_runs$Dest),
      actionButton("go", "") 
    ),


    mainPanel(

      tableOutput(
        "view"))
  )
)
```

server code :

```
server<- function(input, output){
  origin <- input$origin
  destination <- input$destination
  observeEvent(input$go,source("nr9.R")) 
               output$summary <- renderPrint({
                 #dataset <- datasetInput()
                 summary(Tnetwork)
               })
```

Can you please tell me how to get correct results.

Comment: Try this one : `observeEvent(input$go,{
    origin <- input$origin
    destination <- input$destination
    source("nr9.R")}) 
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    #dataset <- datasetInput()
    summary(Tnetwork)
  })`

Comment: input$origin and input$destination won't invalidate unless you use `reactive()`. Try using `reactive(input$origin)` and `reactive(input$destination)`. If this doesn't solve, it would help to know what is in 'nr9.R'

Comment: jyjek -I tried that, but I am getting this error : Warning: Error in eval: object 'input' not found
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: Hi Chris - nr9.R contains script which uses origin and destination as input and gives output of route it follows

Comment: @Arav if you are getting the error input not found, it is often because your sourced file is not local. Try adding `local=T` as a parameter in `source()`

Comment: @Chris- the code is still not taking any input, I ensured that variable names are same, but the varibles are not present  in the environment

Comment: @Arav it's going to be hard to help i'm afraid without being able to run the code myself. Can you make a reproducible example that can be run without external data eg) nr9.R and milk_runs? Did you try wrapping the input$origin and destination  in `reactive()` ?

Comment: I am giving an example here:
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Network Model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "origin",
                  label = "Origin:",
                  choices = "A","B","C","D","E","F"),
      selectInput(inputId = "destination",
                  label = "Destination:",
                  choices = "A","B","C","D","E","F",),
      actionButton("go", "GO") 
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput(
        "view"))
  )
)
nr9.R is code which contains routes 
ex: Origin :A,Destination:E,Route : A-B-E

Comment: @Arav can you give the example as an update to your question? Can you also update the server code as I don't have access to your "nr9.R` file

Comment: server code:
server<- function(input, output){
    observeEvent(input$go,
               origin <- reactive(input$origin),
               destination<-reactive(input$destination),
               paste(Origin,nextword,Destination,sep="-") 
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    #dataset <- datasetInput() 
    summary(Tnetwork) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Comment: @Arav, the code you provided in the comments has quite some mistakes in it..

Comment: @Chris- Let me give a better example instead of the above one
Let df contain all the alphabets individually(df[1] <- "A",df[2]<-"B")
input origin,destination from ui
if(match(origin,df) < match(destination,df)){
Route <- paste(origin,df[match(origin,df)+1),destination,sep="-")
}else{Route <- paste(origin,df[match(destination,df)-1),destination,sep="-")}

Comment: @SeGA can you please tell me which comment, if its server code comment use the latest example.Thanks

Comment: The ui/server code from the 8 & 10 comment. If you copy & paste & run it, you will see the errors.. But @Chris answer has a correct version of your code already.

Answer (score 1):

I think (it would help if you provided a fully reproducible example) that the error is occurring because you are trying to run `input$origin` without `reactive()`. The input$origin will not invalidate and update based on user input unless put inside `reactive`. Based on the example you provided:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Network Model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "origin", label = "Origin:", choices = c("A","B","C","D","E","F")),
      selectInput(inputId = "destination", label = "Destination:", choices = c("A","B","C","D","E","F")),
      actionButton("go", "GO")
      ),
    mainPanel( tableOutput( "view"))
    ) 
  ) 

server<- function(input, output){
  origin <- reactive(input$origin)
  destination<-reactive(input$destination)
  observeEvent(input$go,{
               cat(origin(),'nextword',destination(),sep="-")
  })

  output$view <- renderTable({data.frame(origin=origin(),destination=destination())})
}




shinyApp(ui, server)
```

should print 'origin-nextword-destination' to the console when 'go' is activated, and the table should update. I changed a few bits in your example because it was not reproducible but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hey Chris- the code works fine as its is just  reactive output,but does not work when I want to run a source code it doesn't work and shows the error : [No stack trace available]

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging. Try simply copying and pasting the code within `nr9.r` in place of `source()`. Did you try `source('nr9.R',local=T)` ?

Comment: I have tried both, I understand that the server is not running my code, because no variables are being created in the environment

Comment: @Arav without seeing your script it is hard to help! I did notice you may want to include `source` inside of `renderPrint({})` rather than outside.